# How to get result table from two tables without common field between tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as shown below.

[image: First Table]

[image]

Consider that there is no such relationship between the tables.

So I need my result table should have like this as shown below.

[image]

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

"AcctRef", in your DebitNoteTable, is a ["repeating column"](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/normalizing-repeated-columns-simple-pc.html).

That's a big, huge, no-no :)

You're debit table should look something like this:

```
Debit No  AcctRef
--------  -------
DN1       CMP1
DN1       CMP3
DN1       CMP6
...
```

Then you could do a simple "join" ;)

Here's a good overview of normalization.  I definitely encourage you to revisit your schema, if at all possible:

- http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

If you *can't*, then I guess "Plan B" would be write a program that:

- reads all the prices and stores them in a table
- reads all the AcctRef's for all the debits
- Parses each AcctRef into individual accruals
- prints the price and each debit for each accrual

This effectively means reading all the data in the entire database and then reorganizing it manually.  If you're going to do that, why bother with a database in the first place?

PS:
It's unfortunate that you used a bitmap for your tables.  Text would have been much nicer ;)

Comment: Here by considering AccRef from Table-1 and AccrualNo from Table-2, we need to find the result. Here common means these two only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Since the table is not normalized, you have to do the below steps.. Keeping comma separated values in a column is a bad idea. For any kind of operation on the table you have to split  it..

**Step 1:** You have to create the following function to split the accRef column

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SDF_SplitString]
(
    @sString varchar(2048),
    @cDelimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE ( part varchar(2048) )
AS
BEGIN
    if @sString is null return
    declare     @iStart int,
                @iPos int
    if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
    begin
        set     @iStart = 2
        insert into @tParts
        values( null )
    end
    else 
        set     @iStart = 1
    while 1=1
    begin
        set     @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
        if @iPos = 0
                set     @iPos = len( @sString )+1
        if @iPos - @iStart > 0                  
                insert into @tParts
                values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
        else
                insert into @tParts
                values( null )
        set     @iStart = @iPos+1
        if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
                break
    end
    RETURN

END
```

**step 2:**

Use this query to get the result

```
with cte as(
select * from DebitNote cross apply dbo.SDF_SplitString(AccRef,','))
select part,price,[Debit No]=STUFF((SELECT ', ' + DebitNo
           FROM cte b 
           WHERE b.part = a.part 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cte a join AccrualNote
on part=AccrualNo
GROUP BY part,price
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84910/1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be something like:

```
SELECT a.Accrual_No, a.Price, d.Debit_no FROM AccrualNote AS a, DebitNote as d
WHERE a.Accrual_No IN d.AccRef
```

Next you need to create a loop for the records you get using this query (just try it using phpMyAdmin

(sure paulsm4 is absolutly right, but maybe you can't change the table structure)

Comment: Its not working... Please give some other solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_Get_DebitNo] ( @AccrualNo VARCHAR(20) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @DebitNo VARCHAR(100)
    SET @DebitNo = ''
    SELECT  @DebitNo = @DebitNo + ',' + DebitNo
    FROM    DebitNote
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(@AccrualNo, AccRef) > 0
    SELECT  @DebitNo = RIGHT(@DebitNo, LEN(@DebitNo) - 1)
    RETURN @DebitNo
END
```

The sql works well, I'v test it already, you just need to create a Scalar-values Function as below.

```
SELECT  AccrualNo ,
    Price ,
    dbo.F_Get_DebitNo(AccrualNo) FROM    AccrualNote
```